# Remove empty spaces in delimited text (using StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Tags: vb.net, printing

I try to remove empty spaces using with **StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries** before print the text but when I run the codes "The index was outside the bounds of the array" appears on the screen as an error.

Could you please help to solve that problem?

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim myfile As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim allines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
        For Each line As String In allines
            ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sayı As Integer = TextBox3.Text
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If (TextBox3.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter number")
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        Else
            If TextBox1.TextLength = TextBox3.Text Then
                Dim fields() As String = ListBox1.Text.Split(";")
                Dim idx As Integer = ListBox1.FindString(TextBox1.Text)
                If idx <> -1 Then
                    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = idx
                    ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(0))
                    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Text)
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    PrintDocument1.Print()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim drawfont As New Font("arial", 16)
        Dim drawbrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        Dim fields() As String = ListBox1.Text.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(0)), drawfont, drawbrush, 100, 50)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(1)), drawfont, drawbrush, 100, 70)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(2)), drawfont, drawbrush, 100, 90)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(3)), drawfont, drawbrush, 100, 110)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(4)), drawfont, drawbrush, 100, 130)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(7)), drawfont, drawbrush, 10, 20)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(10)), drawfont, drawbrush, 270, 20)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You would be well served to install an existing CSV parsing library like [CSVhelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which will make working with CSVs almost fun if not painless.

Comment: Look at your code!  The length of the array `fields` is variable, yet your code assumes that the length is at least 11 items long (`fields(10)`).  Also, please read through [Getting Started with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx) and the associated topics.  Learning that will help you more than any forum can.

Comment: When using `Fonts`, `Brushes`, `Pens` or other graphics objects use the `Using/End Using` blocks for them - follows best practice.